# In Azure DevOps is it possible to write a WIQL that would return commits associated with several work items?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps is it possible to write a WIQL that would return commits associated with several work items?

I am writing this sentence just to satisfy the SO requirements for a good question, because I do not know what more to add.

Comment: WIQL returns work item, not commits. what do you try to achieve? maybe in Rest API it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query defined using the Work Item Query Language (WIQL) consists of a SELECT statement that lists the fields to be returned as columns in the result set.

You can further qualify the result set by using a logical expression.

You can specify a sort order. Use an ASOF clause to state that a query is evaluated as of a previous time.

However, just as *Shayki Abramczyk* mentioned in comment, the return results should still be work items. It will not return any commits.

If you want to get commits with linked work items, you could use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to handle this.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.historyMode={searchCriteria.historyMode}&searchCriteria.includePushData={searchCriteria.includePushData}&searchCriteria.includeUserImageUrl={searchCriteria.includeUserImageUrl}&searchCriteria.includeWorkItems={searchCriteria.includeWorkItems}&searchCriteria.includeLinks={searchCriteria.includeLinks}&searchCriteria.$top={searchCriteria.$top}&searchCriteria.$skip={searchCriteria.$skip}&searchCriteria.excludeDeletes={searchCriteria.excludeDeletes}&searchCriteria.itemPath={searchCriteria.itemPath}&searchCriteria.author={searchCriteria.author}&searchCriteria.user={searchCriteria.user}&searchCriteria.toCommitId={searchCriteria.toCommitId}&searchCriteria.fromCommitId={searchCriteria.fromCommitId}&searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionOptions={searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionOptions}&searchCriteria.compareVersion.version={searchCriteria.compareVersion.version}&searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionType={searchCriteria.compareVersion.versionType}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionOptions={searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionOptions}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={searchCriteria.itemVersion.version}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionType={searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionType}&searchCriteria.toDate={searchCriteria.toDate}&searchCriteria.fromDate={searchCriteria.fromDate}&searchCriteria.ids={searchCriteria.ids}&api-version=5.0
```

There is an option `searchCriteria.includeWorkItems` used to indicate whether to include linked work items.

Comment: REST API doesn't work properly, for example, it doesn't return all commits if it was a merge between branches. It just returns the single merge commit, but not the actual commits that were merged.

Comment: @HamsterWithPitchfork This is a conceptual gap between what you're expecting and what a branch is. A branch is a tag which is moved to the child every time a commit happens. It is nothing more. As a result, conceptually, a merge commit is nothing more than a commit with 2+ parents. Another way to think about it is that a branch/commit is the top of some chain of commits, however, no information is stored about _where that chain of commits started_.